# Unknown field on INNER JOIN from multi databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO wk1_tbl (shohin_code, shohin_mei, variation_flag)                                                                                   
SELECT  ha.HINCD, ha.HINNMA, if (g.goods_para_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS  variation                                                                                   
FROM ( SELECT KOSHINCD, count(HINCD) AS quatity                                                                                 
       FROM sc.HINMTF                                                                           
       GROUP BY KOSHINCD ) AS group_set                                                                         
       INNER JOIN  sc.HINMTA ha
        ON ha.HINCD = group_set.KOSHINCD                                                                                
       INNER JOIN master_hankoya.goods g 
        ON ha.WEBHINID = g.goods_id                                                                                 
WHERE ha.HINKB = '2' and ha.DATKB <> '9';
```

I using INNER JOIN on multi-database ,so that you can see `sc` and `master_hankoya` is difference databases
When I run it ,I get error :

`Unknown column 'g.goods_id ' in 'on clause'`

You can see `g` alias for table `master_hankoya.goods`,and `goods_id` is a column in this

I guess that I have problem with INNER JOIN

Please help me correct it

**Update : I check again and take a silly problem ,have a special character in query make it failed to run**

Comment: can you post the table structure of `goods` table?

Comment: I updated structure of goods

Comment: I would suggest you to break your query to small parts and execute. It would be easy to solve it yourself.

Comment: can you post here all table structure and few rows of each table. so I can analysis your query and let you know the reason..

Answer (score 0):

Don't use alias name for master_hankoya.goods like

```
INSERT INTO wk1_tbl (shohin_code, shohin_mei, variation_flag)                                                                                   
SELECT  ha.HINCD, ha.HINNMA, if (master_hankoya.goods.goods_para_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS  variation                                                                                   
FROM ( SELECT KOSHINCD, count(HINCD) AS quatity                                                                                 
   FROM sc.HINMTF                                                                           
   GROUP BY KOSHINCD ) AS group_set                                                                         
   INNER JOIN  sc.HINMTA ha
    ON ha.HINCD = group_set.KOSHINCD                                                                                
   INNER JOIN master_hankoya.goods  
    ON ha.WEBHINID = master_hankoya.goods.goods_id                                                                                 
WHERE ha.HINKB = '2' and ha.DATKB <> '9';
```

Comment: sorry ,I'm  forgot to mention in question , I join on tables from multi databases ,`master_hankoya` is a database and `goods` is a table on this db

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO wk1_tbl (shohin_code, shohin_mei, variation_flag)                                                                                   
SELECT  ha.HINCD, ha.HINNMA, if (g.goods_para_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS  variation                                                                                   
FROM ( SELECT KOSHINCD, count(HINCD) AS quatity                                                                                 
       FROM sc.HINMTF                                                                           
       GROUP BY KOSHINCD ) AS group_set                                                                         
       INNER JOIN  sc.HINMTA ha
        ON ha.HINCD = group_set.KOSHINCD                                                                                
       INNER JOIN
        (select * from master_hankoya.goods ) g
        ON ha.WEBHINID = g.goods_id                                                                                 
WHERE ha.HINKB = '2' and ha.DATKB <> '9';
```

Comment: @it will be if you replace * with only that columns from good table which you want...

Comment: Could you help me explain why my query not work , because I see that I can using the same syntax in `INNER JOIN  sc.HINMTA ha` . In this ,`sc` is a database ,

Comment: Try to wrtie your query by sepifying full qualified table name like..DB.Table.Columnname...

Answer (score -1):

```
   INNER JOIN  sc.HINMTA ha
```

Change this line to:

```
INNER JOIN  HINMTA AS ha
```

INNER JOIN master_hankoya.goods g

Change that line to

INNER JOIN goods AS g

The syntax for setting an alias for a table is:

```
table_name AS table_alias
```

Comment: Sorry , I using INNER JOIN on multi-database ,so that you can see sc and master_hankoya is difference databases